# mac like gestures in elementary OS

Tags: release-hera, gesture

I came across this the other day: https://medium.com/@s0rata/gesture-setup-on-elementary-os-fce53997a50

I have installed '*gestures*' on my PC. But I cannot get the hang of adding new gesture commands to the app. How can I add mac like gestures?

[image]

Comment: There's my configuration file
https://we.tl/t-7imOGzJsSY

Comment: What do I do with the downloaded config file now?

Comment: You can import it in Gestures app by using the Import function from menu.

Comment: I imported the files but it doesn't work. Should I restart?

Comment: Yeah. Also you need to follow every step from the article

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to post detailed information so that it is simple enough for someone with zero technical knowledge to easily understand.